# Using the tooltipDialog with href property but the content never loads?

Tags: xpages

I want to load content from a url in the tooltipDialog and I am using the href property. It just shows a blank toolip?  Has anyone gotten this to work?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">

    <xp:label value="Label" id="label1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[XSP.openTooltipDialog("#{id:tooltipDialog1}", "#{id:label1}")]]></xp:this.script>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:label>
    <xe:tooltipDialog id="tooltipDialog1"
        href="http://www.netexperts.com" loadingMessage="Loading"
        errorMessage="Error">
    </xe:tooltipDialog>
</xp:view>
```

thanks, Howard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Daniel's suggestion, adding a Dojo Content Pane into the tooltipDialog worked fine.

Comment: http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/defect.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=85BF31A20C178CCB862578CC002CC96E

Answer (score 3):

The web browser doesn't load content from other domains for security reasons. Only URLs which point to the current server/ domain can be displayed. If you want to load content from other domains you need a proxy which is reachable under your domain and delivers the content to the web browser.

Try to load a xpage  from the same database, that should work.

Comment: It still does not work.  I created a page in the database and tried both a relative url along with a full url.  Nothing loaded and no error message appears in the tooltipDialog.

Comment: I used the dojo tooltip dialog without using the extension library and had no problems with the href property. 

Using your provided xpages markup the href property did not work for me too. 

The following workaround might help:

`<xe:tooltipDialog id="tooltipDialog1">
    <xe:djContentPane id="djContentPane1" href="otherXpage.xsp" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></xe:djContentPane>
</xe:tooltipDialog>`